# $X$ is a Banach space for the norm $\|u\| := \sup_{t \ge 0} e^{-kt} |u(t)|$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a Banach space, $k>0$ and
$$
X := \{u \in C([0, \infty); E) : \sup_{t \ge 0} e^{-kt} |u(t)| < \infty\}.
$$

In the proof of *Theorem 7.3* from Brezis' *Funtional Analysis*, the author said that

> $X$ is a Banach space for the norm
> $$
> \|u\| := \sup_{t \ge 0} e^{-kt} |u(t)|.
> $$

Could you confirm if my attempt on the completeness of $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ is fine?

---

Let $(u_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. For a fixed $t \ge 0$, we have $(u_n (t))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and thus converges in $E$. Let $v(t) := \lim_n u_n (t) \in E$. Let's prove that $\|u_n - v\| \to 0$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. There is $N >0$ such that $\|u_n - u_m\| <\varepsilon$ for all $n,m>N$. Then for $n>N$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\|u_n-v\| &= \sup_{t \ge 0} e^{-kt} |u_n(t) -v(t)| \\
&= \sup_{t \ge 0} \lim_m e^{-kt}  |u_n(t) - u_m(t)| \\
&\le \sup_{t \ge 0} \limsup_m \|u_n-u_m\| \\
&=  \limsup_m \|u_n-u_m\| \\
&\le \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
$$

It remains to verify that $v$ is continuous. Fix $t_0 > 0$. We will prove that $v$ is continuous at $t_0$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\|u_N - v\| <\varepsilon$. Since $u_N$ is continuous at $t_0$, there is $0<\delta<1$ such that $|u_N (t)-u_N(t_0)| < \varepsilon$ for all $t \ge 0$ with $|t-t_0| <\delta$. By triangle inequality, we have for $t \ge 0$ with $|t-t_0| <\delta$:
$$
\begin{align*}
|v(t)-v(t_0)| & \le |v(t)-u_N(t)|+|u_N(t)-u_N(t_0)|+|u_N(t_0) - v(t_0)| \\
&\le \|v-u_N\|e^{kt} + \varepsilon+ \|v-u_N\|e^{kt_0} \\
&\le \|v-u_N\|e^{k(t_0+\delta)} + \varepsilon+ \|v-u_N\|e^{kt_0} \\
&\le (e^{k(t_0+1)}+e^{kt_0}+1)\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
$$

The claim then follows.

Comment: Looks mostly OK.  To prove continuity, perhaps show that $u_n$ converges uniformly, and cite the theorem that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous (instead of re-doing the proof).  You should also verify that $v \in E$.